# Code for counting the number of syllables in the words in a file

Tags: python, nltk

I have the following piece of code so far to count the number of syllables in the words in the cmudict ( CMU pronunciation dictionary). It counts the number of syllables for all the words in the dictionary. Now I need to replace cmudict with my input file and find the number of syllables for each word in the file which is printed as output. Just opening the input file in read mode does not work as dict() cannot be provided as the attribute to the file. 
The code is given below :

```
  
from curses.ascii import isdigit 
from nltk.corpus import cmudict 

d = cmudict.dict() # get the CMU Pronouncing Dict

def nsyl(word): 
    """return the max syllable count in the case of multiple pronunciations"""
    return max([len([y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1])]) for x in d[word.lower()]])


w_words = dict([(w, nsyl(w)) for w in d.keys() if w[0] == 'a'or'z'])
worth_abbreviating = [(k,v) for (k,v) in w_words.iteritems() if v > 3]
print worth_abbreviating
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: And this code is for printing words with a syllable count of more than 3. So it helps to determine the complex words based on syllable count.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this will solve the whole problem, but:

```
w_words = dict([(w, nsyl(w)) for w in d.keys() if w[0] == 'a'or'z'])
```

should probably be

```
w_words = dict([(w, nsyl(w)) for w in d.keys() if w[0] == 'a' or w[0] == 'z'])
```

since

`if w[0] == 'a'or'z'` means `if (w[0] == 'a') or ('z')`.  The string `'z'` is Truish, so the condition is always True.

For example,

```
In [36]: 'x' == 'a'or'z'
Out[36]: 'z'

In [37]: 'x' == 'a' or 'x'=='z'
Out[37]: False
```

Comment: No the code works fine and displays all the words( from a to z) along with their syllable count. What I need to do is do the same for an input file.

Comment: In that case `w_words = dict([(w, nsyl(w)) for w in d.keys() if w[0] == 'a'or'z'])` could be shortened to `w_words = dict([(w, nsyl(w)) for w in d.keys()])`.  Can you post a snippet of the contents of the input file?

Comment: Oh right! It works for the shortened form too :) The input file is sample.txt which contains the following text :  I am flabbergasted by your flamboyance, it is condescending on your part to deny my request while I never abnegate yours in the earnest. Your actions are both conundrumic and melodramatic. For your next errand you are not going to punch my mobile number on your cell.